# Sveltekit "Files and directories prefixed with __ are reserved" error

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I tried using named layout but when running `npm run dev --open` it gives me this error

```sh
> Files and directories prefixed with __ are reserved (saw src/routes/auth/__layout-auth.svelte)
    at file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:193:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:178:32)
    at file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:235:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:211:9)
    at create_manifest_data (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:296:2)
    at update (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/sync.js:911:24)
    at update_manifest (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:59:31)
    at Object.configureServer (file:///home/gwendal/Documents/SvelteKit/ninja-gaming/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:191:4)
```

I have a layout called `__layout-auth.svelte` located in `src/routes/auth`

Comment: Do you have any files and directories with "__" in their name?

Comment: I have `__layout-auth.svelte` in `src/routes/auth`,  `__layout.svelte` and `__error.svelte` in `/src/routes`

Comment: did you update sveltekit to at least version .306 ?

Comment: I use svelte 3.44.0

Comment: I mean the sveltekit version

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm at version 1.0.0-next.324.

Comment: I just ran npm update and it seems to have solved the problem